# How to make an Android app to work between specific dates?

Tags: android

I would like to make an Android app to work between 5/5/15 and 10/10/15.
Do I have to use a .xml file or a .java file?

Please help me.

Comment: Function means Do you want the application only to run on specific dates or the applications task to be done on certain date. Be specific and elaborate your question?

Answer (score 0):

you would definitely use Java to handle such thing, if xml was for that then why android used java? anyway to do such thing, you'll have two options, either you save the start date and end date to `preferences` or to local `database`, and then you could use `alarmManager` to check if that the day has come, or simply check whenever the user opens the application.

Comment: Thanks k0sh. I think simply checking whenever the user opens the application is the easiest thing. I don't know the steps about setting date using preference and alarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is called "Freemium" app, that means user can use the app for lets say a week or 10 days and then the app will stop working or redirect the user to paid version on the playstore.

This can be achieved mainly by 3 techniques 
1) The first approach is very simple you store two dates in the `sharedpreferences` and then compare the two dates, and every time you run the app after that check to see if the trial period has ended.

2) The second approach is placing a hardcoded time bomb , by this method all the users will be logged at the same time on the same date and hence wont be able to use the app further more

3) Third approach, the best practice to achieve the above. You will have to setup a server and when your application is started it sends a unique phone identifier to the server. Then on the server you can check if the phone id is new or old used one

For better user experience you should show a popup(alertdialog) or something, so that the user is redirected to the paid version or full app version on playstore.

Comment: if you think the answer is right and  has helped you, please approve the answer so that it is helpful to others.